# BNF syntax for a recursive function?

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages, compilers, parsers, syntax

I'm to write a syntax that will allow for a recursive function, i.e.

```
f(x) = if x == 0 then x else f(x+1)
```

Here's one attempt at creating the grammar:
[image]

But I don't think this is right since there's no such thing as parameterized syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aiming to simply allow recursive functions or specify only recursive functions. The following grammar allows recursive functions:

```
function      := id '(' parameter ')' '=' function_body ;
function_body := conditional
               | expression
               ;
expression    := function_call
               | <other expression types>
               ;
function_call := id '(' parameter ')' ;
```

Specifying only recursive functions would require a context-aware grammar (BNF is context-free). You can approach the problem outside of the grammar specification though and check for recursive functions later in your parser / compiler pipeline.

Checking for recursion outside of the grammar allows you to more easily identify cyclic recursion (not just `f` calling `f` but something like `f -> a -> b -> c -> f`).

Comment: how does this grammar allow recursive functions?

Comment: @gust I've edited my answer to make the grammar more clear. Consider a recursive function such as `f(x) = f(x)`. This is allowed by the grammar as `id '(' parameter ')' '='` matches `f(x) =` and the function body can be an expression such as a call to `f(x)`.